# DataBind List<Tuple<DateTime, Boolean>> into a Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater, bind, tuples

Ok, I can't cast `System.Tuple'2[System.DateTime,System.Boolean]` into `System.Collections.Generic.List'1[System.Tuple'2[System.DateTime,System.Boolean]]` (the system show the exception in the line that I put the comment ***Error*** in the code below)

But how could I bind my `List<Tuple>` in my repeater.

There is no way to accomplish this without creating an Interface or Class just for the sake of this task.

**Here is the my code**

```
#region Fields
ControllerProg controllerProg = new ControllerProg();
List<Tuple<DateTime, Boolean>> lstDatePagination = new List<Tuple<DateTime, Boolean>>();
List<DateTime> dtPag = new List<DateTime>();
#endregion

dtPag = controllerProg.ListDates(15);
if (dtPag.Count > 0)
{
    double j = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
        if (dtPag.Count > i && dtPag[i] != null)
        {
            lstDatePagination.Add(Tuple.Create(dtPag[i], true));
        }
        else
        {
            lstDatePagination.Add(Tuple.Create(dtPag.Last().AddDays(j), false));
            j++;
        }
    }
    rptPagination.DataSource = lstDatePagination;
    rptPagination.DataBind();
}

protected void rptPagination_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        // Error
        List<Tuple<DateTime, Boolean>> datePagination = (List<Tuple<DateTime, Boolean>>)e.Item.DataItem;
        // InvalidCastException was unhandled by user code

        Label lblDay = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblDay");
        lblDay.Text = datePagination[0].Item1.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
        lblDay.Enabled = datePagination[0].Item2;
    }
}
```

To create a short explanation about the code is that I'm getting all dates in one specific select, filling the gap in a `for`

My question is really about how can I bind a List into a `RepeaterItemEventArgs` without Interfaces and Classes. (Like we do with List<>)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure you can't cast a `Tuple<DateTime, Boolean>` into a `List<Tuple<DateTime, Boolean>>`.  Try:

```
protected void rptPagination_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        // Error
        Tuple<DateTime, Boolean> datePagination = (Tuple<DateTime, Boolean>)e.Item.DataItem;

        Label lblDay = (Label)FindControl("lblDay");
        lblDay.Text = datePagination.Item1.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
        lblDay.Enabled = datePagination.Item2;
    }
}
```

Comment: That was so simple and so obvious that I'm a little ashamed of have asked this. Works without trouble =) Tyvm